# Exclusive fullscreen using VK_EXT_full_screen_exclusive in Vulkan 1.1?

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I read that using exclusive fullscreen improves the performance of an application as it bypasses the window manager. It seems that the `VK_EXT_full_screen_exclusive` extension serves for this exact purpose. I found that to use it, all I have to do is to call

```
VkResult vkAcquireFullScreenExclusiveModeEXT(
    VkDevice                                    device,
    VkSwapchainKHR                              swapchain);
```

It just seems a bit too easy to be like this for me, so I wanted to ask if I understood correctly that the only thing I have to do is to simply call this single function. I would also use some general advice on this topic.

If it is important, I am using GLFW for all my windowing stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to read the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_EXT_full_screen_exclusive) directly. It will list the added functions and structs, so you get the idea about the scale of the extension. And Valid Usage sections tells you exactly if all you have to do is call it or not.

IMO more importantly, exclusive fullscreen reduces input latency. If it goes through the compositor it automatically adds at least one full frame of latency.

Also it is painfully clear when the driver should enable exclusive fullscreen on its own without the need for an extension. What this extension adds is only explicit control of this. If the compositor is off can be verified with [PresentMon](https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon/releases/).

Now to the usage:

- if you want to use `vkAcquireFullScreenExclusiveModeEXT`, your swapchain must be created with `VK_FULL_SCREEN_EXCLUSIVE_APPLICATION_CONTROLLED_EXT`
- if you use `VK_FULL_SCREEN_EXCLUSIVE_APPLICATION_CONTROLLED_EXT`, the "exclusiveness" can get lost and you need to handle that
- using the extension may impact the returns from the surface queries (and you need to use the extension `pNext` struct)
- the `VK_FULL_SCREEN_EXCLUSIVE_APPLICATION_CONTROLLED_EXT` can only be used if `fullScreenExclusiveSupported` cap is supported
- the extension is only supported on Windows

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! If I may, could you please expand on the topic of what are the conditions that allow the driver to enable exclusive fullscreen on its own?

Comment: @enthusiastic_3d_graphics_pr... It can be a bit finicky. Though in modern OS I would expect any undecorated screen-covering opaque window using 3D api to get exclusive. Firstly, there's this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenablecomposition saying it cannot be done programmatically in Windows 8+. Then there's this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/for-best-performance--use-dxgi-flip-model#what-do-i-have-to-do-to-use-the-flip-model I think it lists some things that might prevent exclusive.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to check if specific vulkan extension is available during runtime? like in opengl we can do glGetString(GL_EXT_***) and see whether a specific GL_EXT is available or not

Comment: @Zennichimaro yes

Comment: @krOoze how? would you mind sharing the function call? eg: the `glGetString()` equivalent..

Comment: @Zennichimaro Look it up in the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#extendingvulkan-extensions). Respectfully, I am not an internet search engine, and low level APIs are not suitable for people that need to be told the most basic of stuff.